# $wpdb - sort by two meta value

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, wordpress

I have "type" custom field and two value (free and paid). I need get "paid" posts first in loop, and free latest. How can I sort my query? I can't use wp_query.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "
    SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta m1
      ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = m1.post_id )
    WHERE
        $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'object'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND ( m1.meta_key = 'type' AND m1.meta_value = $type )
    GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date
    DESC;
  ";
```

Comment: Would be easy if you include some data sample and desire output.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently sorting by post_date, so the oldest ones will display first, and the newest last. For all the rows of the same date, mysql will decide on the order. If you want to keep this date sequence, but always show the paid ones first on a particular date, then you can just add a second sort attribute:

```
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date, meta_value DESC
```

DESC will make sure 'paid' comes before 'free', if those are your actual values. This is also assuming there are only two values. If you might have more values, then it could be worth investigating the mysql [CASE expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: I have more 50 custom fields on post. I dont want keep order by date.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "
SELECT *
FROM $wpdb->posts
INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta m1
  ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = m1.post_id )
INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta m2   //add this line
ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = m2.post_id ) //add this line
WHERE
    $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'object'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND ( m1.meta_key = 'city' AND m1.meta_value = $city_string )
AND ( m2.meta_key = 'type' ) //add this line
GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
ORDER BY m2.meta_value //add this line
DESC;
";
```